# Install backup of my old Mac on my new one

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, catalina, partition, apfs

I got a new MacBook Pro with Catalina on it. I made a APFS formatted Copy of my old Mac and want to install it on a separate Partition on my new MacBook Pro so that when I start the new MacBook I can switch between the new one and the old one but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This site doesn't focus on 'how to' or tutorials.  There are many other sites that can offer step-by-step instructions, such as [this overview](https://support.apple.com/en-euro/HT203981) from Apple.  If you run into a specific problem, we'd be happy to help you get thru it, though.

Comment: What OS was the old Mac running? If it's earlier than Catalina, then your new Mac probably won't boot from the older OS (because that OS doesn't know about hardware from its future).
If both OSes are the same, then what's the point of having two identical OSes?

Comment: @benwiggy the old one is running Mojave

Comment: If the new MacBook *came with Catalina from the factory,* you can't do what you're looking to do because you cannot boot/install an older version of macOS than what came on your Mac.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356138/119271

Comment: @Jonathan You probably can't boot Mojave on a brand new Mac. Why do you want two separate OS volumes? You can just copy the apps, documents, and preferences over to the new OS volume using Migration Assistant.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Disk Utility to create a new APFS volume in your current APFS container. Next, download macOS Catalina from Apple App Store which will appear as the `Install macOS Catalina` application. Run this application and install Catalina in the new volume. Boot to the new volume and run the Migration Assistant application to transfer applications and data from the old Mac. This transfer is in the form of a copy. In other words, nothing is removed from the old Mac.